# Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL (my url) Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, web-services, wsdl, glassfish

I use payara server and postgres database. I can deploy my project successsfully. I also can open the wsdl page. But I can not open the test page. And when I saw the server log. It show that: [log information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yU3Y.png)

But I think I have the jdk.

Any help is appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this problem. It said I didnot have jdk. In my ec2 instance, it really has a openjdk. So I think maybe I can not use open jdk. I download oracal jdk 8 from the web. Finally, it is success. If someone get this problem, maybe it can help you.